# JOLT - Conditional dynamic default values

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need a transformation that shifts data from one array to another directly. My main problem is that the input `dependant` array might be empty sometimes. For those cases, there is a `master` array which defines the length of the `result` array.

To sum things up, I need to:

- Shift the data from `dependant` to `result`.
- Specify default values depending on the `master` array length if no data was shifted.

A couple of examples:

#### CASE 1 (Shifts data normally)

Input:

```json
{
  "master": [
    {
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2"
    }
  ],
  "dependant": [
    {
      "data": "AA"
    },
    {
      "data": "BB"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
  "result": [ "AA", "BB" ]
}
```

#### CASE 2

`dependant` array is empty and we need to create the `result` array with the same length as `master`. Each element can be any string such as `DEFAULT`.

Input:

```json
{
  "master": [
    {
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2"
    }
  ],
  "dependant": []
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "result": [ "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consecutively apply **modify-overwrite-beta** and **shift** transformations such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "szdependant": "=size(@(1,dependant))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "szdependant": {
        "0": {
          "@(2,master)": { "*": { "#DEFAULT": "result" } }
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,dependant)": { "*": { "*": "result" } }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to use the size value(`szdependant`) of the `dependant` list as a conditional statement within the **shift** transformation step

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried to adapt this solution into my problem and looks like I have not defined the problem properly. I will be creating a new question as this solution solves the problem exposed.

Comment: you're welcome @DavidSegovia wish success for your studies

Comment: Thanks :) Link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255003/jolt-join-arrays-in-nested-array