# JOLT - Join arrays in nested array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to achieve the following transformation. However, my solution adds undesired null values into the final array.

The transformation needs to shift names in `child` array for all `root` elements. I have created 3 cases to illustrate the problem.

#### Case 1

##### Input

```json
{
  "root": [
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "name": "Frazer"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Brandon"
        },
        {
          "name": "Josef"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Desired Output

```json
{
  "NAMES": ["John,Frazer","Brandon,Josef"]
}
```

#### Case 2: One `child` is empty

##### Input

```json
{
  "root": [
    {
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Brandon"
        },
        {
          "name": "Josef"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Desired Output

```json
{
   "NAMES": ["","Brandon,Josef"]
}
```

#### Case 3: All `child`s are empty

##### Input

```json
{
  "root": [
    {
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "child": []
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Desired Output

```json
{
   "NAMES": ["",""]
}
```

**EDIT:** `root` array will always have at least 1 element.

Current JOLT spec works fine except for cases where `child` is an empty array. It generates `null` values and I'm trying to specify an **empty string** instead (or any hardcoded string value such as `"NO_NAMES"`)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": {
          "child": {
            "*": {
              "name": "NAMES[&3]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "NAMES": {
        "*": "=trim"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "NAMES": "MANY"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "NAMES": []
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "NAMES": {
        "*": "=join(',',@0)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi David, what spec are you using currently ?

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, thanks your help again. I've added my current spec. The `default` node is one of my attempts but does not help me achieve my goal.

Comment: That is my main problem. I need it to be `{ "NAMES" : [  "", "" ] }` instead. Or `{ "NAMES" : [  "NO_NAMES", "NO_NAMES" ] }`. Both solutions would be valid. `NAMES` should be the same length as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply consecutive transformations **modify-overwrite-beta** and then **shift** in order to determine comma-seperated elements of the list(*unless they have zero size,this case only double quotes will appear*), and then concatenate them within a list such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": {
          "child": { "*": "@(0,name)" },
          "NAMES": "=join(',',@(1,child))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": {
          "NAMES": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```